# Scala slow hashmap

Tags: performance, scala, recursion

For [Project Euler problem 14](https://projecteuler.net/problem=14), I created this answer:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.LongMap

object LongestCollatzSequencePerso {
  def nextElem(n: Long): Long = n match {
    case x if n % 2 == 0 => n / 2
    case _ => 3 * n + 1
  }

  def funcVal(acc: LongMap[Long], n: Long): LongMap[Long] = {
    if (acc.contains(n)) {
      return acc
    }
    else {
      val nNext = nextElem(n)
      val size = funcVal(acc, nNext)(nNext) + 1      
      return acc + (n -> size)
    }
  }

  def main = {
    val max = 1000000L
    val allVal = (1L to max).foldLeft(LongMap(1L -> 1L))(funcVal)
    println(allVal.filter(_._1 < max).maxBy(_._2)._1)
  }
}
```

I use an immutable `LongMap` that caches every result computed so far, in order to stop recursive call as soon as one has to be returned. My code is very slow, and I can not get the result.

Now this code, taken from the Internet, does not cache anything:

```
object LongestCollatzSequenceWeb {  
  def from(n: Long, c: Int = 0): Int = if (n == 1) c + 1 else
    from(if (n % 2 == 0) n / 2 else 3 * n + 1, c + 1)

  val r = (1 until 1000000).view
                           .map(n => (n, from(n)))
                           .reduceLeft((a, b) => if (a._2 > b._2) a else b)
                           ._1

  def main = println(r)
}
```

But it runs fast enough to get the correct answer in a short time.

Why is my cached version so slow ? I understand that caching creates its own overhead, but I was hoping to get a result in a reasonnable time anyway. Do you see a way I could increase the performances while keeping everything immutable ?

I also created this tail recursive version (as suggested in an answer), but it is very slow too:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.collection.immutable.LongMap

object LongestCollatzSequenceTailRec {
  def nextElem(n: Long): Long = n match {
    case x if n % 2 == 0 => n / 2
    case _ => 3 * n + 1
  }

  @tailrec
  def funcVal(acc: (List[Long], LongMap[Long]), n: Long): (List[Long], LongMap[Long]) = {
    val (previous, dic) = acc
    if (dic.contains(n)) {
      val disN = dic(n)
      val dis = disN + 1 to disN + previous.length
      return (Nil, dic ++ previous.zip(dis))
    }
    else {   
      return funcVal((n :: previous, dic), nextElem(n))
    }
  }

  def main = {
    val max = 1000000L
    val allVal = (1L to max).foldLeft((List[Long](), LongMap(1L -> 1L)))(funcVal)
    println(allVal._2.filter(_._1 < max).maxBy(_._2)._1)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Iteration #1**: Initial implementation

It turns out that the version you posted is not tail recursive, just add `@tailrec` annotation to your `funcVal` method and see that it will not compile because recursive call is not in tail position.

On the contrary method `from` in `LongestCollatzSequenceWeb` **is** tail recursive (also checked by adding `@tailrec`).

Now we try to compare apples with oranges or recursive method performance with iterative one :)

**Iteration #2**: After `@tailrec` modification you should clearly see that you create huge amount of memory. Let's prove that by simple **logging of Garbage Collection time**:

```
val scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable {

  override def run(): Unit = {

    val totalTime = ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans.asScala.map(_.getCollectionTime).sum
    println("Spent time for GC: " + totalTime)
  }
}, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

Let's run your code with the `val max = 1000000L`. We will not wait for eternity for it to stop but we will see the following:

```
Spent time for GC: 0
Spent time for GC: 47
Spent time for GC: 67
Spent time for GC: 107
Spent time for GC: 157
Spent time for GC: 201
......................
Spent time for GC: 940
Spent time for GC: 988
Spent time for GC: 1034
......................
```

So shortly we ended up wasting more than **1 second** on GC! Moreover it indicates that garbage collection happened quite frequent.

On the contrary let's try *'code from the internet'* for *100000000 limit* (100 times more than original one):

```
Spent time for GC: 55
Spent time for GC: 58
Spent time for GC: 60
Spent time for GC: 64
```

As you can see we have way less garbage collections (as we allocate less memory) and the pace of growth is slower (`+2 - +4 millis` for each 5 seconds compared to `+40 - +70` in previous sample).

Hope it helps and clearly points to the flaws in your current solution.

Comment: @vkubicki please have a look at update. It analyses memory allocation of your code.

Comment: Thank you for the gc analysis. Do you have a suggestion for an efficient immutable cache, or do you agree with the other answer: I have to turn to a mutable map ? I do project euler exercises to learn about immutability.

Comment: @vkubicki yes, you should use either mutable map or solution without caching which you have already

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in using immutable structures in such algorithms. Simply replace

```
import scala.collection.immutable.LongMap
```

with

```
import scala.collection.mutable.LongMap
```

and change

```
return (Nil, dic ++ previous.zip(dis))
```

to

```
return (Nil, dic ++= previous.zip(dis))
```

and you will see a huge difference. Size of your `dict` is ~2M, so you re-allocate it 2 million times (slightly less since you cache `previous`, but still more than enough). Not worth it.

Comment: Thank you. I do those exercises to learn about immutability. I am a bit disappointed that my solution failed :).